# How can I use RTRIM or REPLACE when I know the length I want to trim but not what it may contain?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to RTRIM the last 7 characters from a result set in an Oracle query. These 7 chars can be anything; spaces, alpha numeric etc... and I don't know the exact length of any value.

So for example I'd like to run something like this

```
 SELECT RTRIM (COl_A, (SELECT LENGTH (COL_A)-7) FROM TABLE_ONE;
```

or a replace equivalent

```
SELECT REPLACE(COL_A, (SELECT LENGTH (COL_A)-7 FROM TABLE_ONE),'');
```

Do I need to do something with SUBSTRING maybe?

I know how to remove/replace specific chars but I'm having trouble when dealing with unknown chars. I've seen a few examples of similar problems but they seem unnecessarily complicated... or does this require a more in depth solution than I think it should?

As always thanks in advance for advice or hints.

Comment: Look at the `LENGTH` function. You need something like `SUBSTR(columnname, 0, LENGTH(columname)-7)`

Comment: I wonder how you can write 'Do I need to do something with SUBSTRING maybe?' and not find the answer yourself.

Comment: As stated I had seen a few examples but nothing that seemed clear enough to me. I was trying to combine RTRIM and LENGTH keywords and then failing that tried to combine LENGTH with REPLACE. I always find that the solutions offered here are clear and concise so thank you to everyone for taking the time to answer my question. I really appreciate the answers and learn something every time I come here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are in search of the `substr` function.

```
select substr(col_a, 1, length(col_a) - 7) from table_one
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the correct solution is:

```
select substr(col_a, 1, (case when length(col_a) < 7 then 0 else length(col_a) - 7 end) from table_one
```

To be general, you would want to take into account what happens when the length is less than 7.

Comment: No need to. If it is, the value passed to the length parameter would be negative, causing the substr functon to return `null` (which is the same as empty string, `''`)

Comment: NULL IS NOT THE SAME AS AN EMPTY STRING!

Comment: Typing it in capitals doesn't make it true. It only makes you impolite. In Oracle an empty string equals null. Just try this: `SELECT '' FROM dual`

Comment: Okay, then look at the ANSI standard specifications for SQL.  I encourage to google "ANSI SQL empty string NULL".  The standard is quite clear that the expression "'' is NULL" evaluations to FALSE.

Comment: Fine. Google says, standards say..  But we're talking Oracle here. Forget everything you know about standards. :)